# Get the top value row of a table without id

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

So i have this table:

| **req_num** | **number** | **status** | **order** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1254 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 1254 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| ***1254*** | ***6*** | ***7*** | ***3*** |
| 1246 | 7 | 8 | 1 |
| 1246 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
| ***1246*** | ***3*** | ***8*** | ***3*** |
| 1253 | 1 | 9 | 1 |
| 1253 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| ***1253*** | ***7*** | ***4*** | ***3*** |
| 1321 | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 1321 | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 1321 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| ***1321*** | ***8*** | ***4*** | ***4*** |

and i need to know if theres a way to generate a query that get a column like this based on the highest value in the "order" column.

| req_num | number | status | order | last_req |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1254 | 5 | 7 | 1 | not_last |
| 1254 | 4 | 7 | 2 | not_last |
| 1254 | 6 | 7 | **3** | ***last*** |
| 1246 | 7 | 8 | 1 | not_last |
| 1246 | 5 | 8 | 2 | not_last |
| 1246 | 3 | 8 | **3** | ***last*** |
| 1253 | 1 | 9 | 1 | not_last |
| 1253 | 4 | 7 | 2 | not_last |
| 1253 | 7 | 4 | **3** | ***last*** |
| 1321 | 7 | 4 | 1 | not_last |
| 1321 | 8 | 4 | 2 | not_last |
| 1321 | 7 | 4 | 3 | not_last |
| 1321 | 8 | 4 | **4** | ***last*** |

this table doesnt have any ids and i can't do inserts on it, any ideas?

Comment: how do you define `order value`?

Comment: What version of Mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window` functions to accomplish this - you can partition your data by `req_num` and then take the item in each partition with the highest `order`.

The docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html

The result will be something like (untested):

```
SELECT rec_num, number, status, LAST_VAL(order) OVER w AS 'last',
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY req_num ORDER BY order);
```

That won't give you exactly what you want as all the rows will now include the highest order num for that rec_num. But you can then easily compare the `order` and `last` columns to create your `last` and `not_last` identifiers.

```
SELECT rec_num, number, status, LAST_VAL(order) OVER w AS 'last',
    IF(`order` = `last`, 'last', 'not_last') AS last_req
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY req_num ORDER BY order);
```

The window functions are remarkably powerful for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, you need to look for the maximum value in the `order` field, grouped by req_num.

If your version is **MySQL 8.0**, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to assign an ordinal value to that column in a descendent way, so that your max value has ranking = 1. Afterwards you check with an `IF` statement if your column has the value 1 or not, and replace with 'last' and 'not_last' accordingly.

```
SELECT *,
       IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY req_num_ ORDER BY order_ DESC) = 1,
          'last',
          'not_last')    AS last_req
FROM tab
```

Demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxZx7bD1TeqSs8w7ckbYPC/0).

---

If your version is **MySQL 5.X**, you can first use the `MAX` aggregation function in a subquery containing only `req_num` and `order`, by grouping on the former field and aggregating on the latter one. Then you can `LEFT JOIN` the original table with this result set, and the `order` values who will have assigned NULL will be the ones that are 'not_last'.

```
SELECT tab.req_num,
       tab.status,
       tab.order,
       IF(max_values.max_order, 'last', 'not_last') AS last_req
FROM      tab 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT req_num_,
                  MAX(order) AS max_order
           FROM tab
           GROUP BY req_num               ) max_values
       ON tab.req_num = max_values.req_num
      AND tab.order = max_values.max_order
```

Demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e4MZXsgnZnobBxCrdJ7urQ/0).